# how to resolve 'yarn package has unmet peer dependency'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I get a load of warnings when I run `yarn upgrade` or `install` because of unmet peerDependencies.

```
warning " > apollo-link-http@1.5.9" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0".
warning " > babel-loader@8.0.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
```

As I understand it, the listed packages need the dependency, and another package in my project has the dependency, I can find the deps but I can't find any information about how to direct the said packages to the sub dependency that I know exists.

How can I get yarn to quiet down and show it where these deps are?

Comment: Just add the dependency yourself.

Comment: then what happens to the dependency that is in my subpackage? is that dependency ignored in favor of the top level one?

Answer (score 43):

Both warnings are about **peer dependencies**, which means that it's **your application's responsibility** to provide those packages as dependencies.

In this case `graphql` and `@babel/core` are expected to be installed in your root app.

Comment: It's weird that none of the documentation for any package managers explains this in a succinct and practical way, like you just did.

Comment: @AndrewKoster I concur. It's even weirder that yarn can't/won't handle the peer dependencies for you. I thought that was the whole point of a package manager!

Comment: Is there any known reason as to why it has to be installed in the root app?