# yarn add firebase gives "unmet peer dependency" warnings

Tags: firebase

`yarn add firebase` gives the following `unmet peer dependency` warnings. Firebase docs don't mention requiring any dependencies: see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize), it's meant to work with `npm install --save firebase`. What am I missing?

```
warning "firebase > @firebase/database@0.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore@1.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions@0.4.7" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/messaging@0.3.20" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/performance@0.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage@0.2.16" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/util@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/database > @firebase/database-types@0.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore > @firebase/firestore-types@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions > @firebase/messaging-types@0.2.11" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/performance > @firebase/installations@0.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage > @firebase/storage-types@0.2.11" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage > @firebase/storage-types@0.2.11" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/util@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/performance > @firebase/installations > @firebase/installations-types@0.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
```

Comment: You're missing the dependencies that it's listing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to resolve 'yarn package has unmet peer dependency'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947699/how-to-resolve-yarn-package-has-unmet-peer-dependency)

Comment: @JJJ, thanks for pointing me to a possible duplicate. Unfortunately, it does not answer my question. It is specific to Firebase - the docs do not mention requiring any dependencies. I have modified the question to clarify this. I am hoping that someone from Firebase could respond.

Comment: There's nothing special about Firebase, it's an npm package like everything else. The issue and solution is exactly the same. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1207#issuecomment-424804228

Comment: Thanks @JJJ. I will add those dependencies and let Firebase team know to update their docs.

Comment: @Naresh You don't need to add any dependencies, it's a `yarn`bug... Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711054/6086782